# Migrating from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect

Tags: php, openid, google-openid, openid-connect

As we know Google Login is migrating from OpenId2.0 to OpenId connect. I have changed my code as like

```
require 'oauth/openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID;

  $openid->realm = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
  $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
  $openid->required = array('contact/email');
  if (!headers_sent()){
       header('Location: '.$openid->authUrl());
  }else{
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
       echo 'window.location.href="'.$openid->authUrl().'";';
       echo '</script>';
   }
        }
```

But it is throwing an error like `invalid parameters sent`. Should I need to add/change anything?

Comment: Is there any more to this code? I can't see the instantiation of this object.

Comment: @halfer I already done it

Comment: Your `HTTP_HOST` should be in quotes. If you can't see the notices this generates, then your errors may be turned off in your development environment. Try turning them on to see if there is something else you might have missed?

Comment: @halfer while migrating from openId2.0 to connect did i need to add anything else?like openid or anything..and if any site you know that explains each step rather than google developers website?

Comment: @Gautam3164 Always use json_encode if you want to send data to javascript. Btw is there an answer yet?