# Registration issue with Gerrit

Tags: linux, oauth, openid, yahoo, gerrit

I have successfully installed gerrit on local centos machine with help of http://dcycleproject.org/blog/82/setting-gerrit-centos-evaluation

On registering gerrit with google, i am facing "OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts has gone away" issue and with yahoo registration, i am getting "The page you requested was not found, or you do not have permission to view this page" error message.

I explored below links but did not find any relative information:
[Migrating from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599622/migrating-from-openid-2-0-to-openid-connect)
[OAuthWebSecurity Migrating from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861572/oauthwebsecurity-migrating-from-openid-2-0-to-openid-connect)

Comment: Was unable to configure gerrit with openid. So i opted for http method for authentication. For this, i have configured gerrit.config and httpd.conf.